# Python Requests ProxyError not caught

Tags: python

Why would the proxy error not be caught by the first except: clause? I am not quite understanding why it is defaulting to the second clause (or if I remove the second cause it will just throw an error)

```
from requests.exceptions import ProxyError

try:
    login(acc)
except ProxyError:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Output:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /mail (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
```

Comment: Who is login and acc? Can you post entire code?

Comment: @gplayer: not needed here, it is clear enough what happens here if you are familiar with the `requests` codebase. The OP is expecting `ProxyError` to catch the exception, but instead the `except Exception` branch fires and the `print e` produces the output shown.

Comment: I see, looks like I'm not familiar enough with those :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've hit a bit of an edge-case here. The `ProxyError` exception is not actually the `requests.exceptions` exception; it an exception with the same name from the embedded `urllib3` library, and it is wrapped in a `MaxRetryError` exception.

This is really a bug, and was indeed filed as such a while ago, see [issue #3050](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3050). It was fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/3059), to raise the proper `requests.exceptions.ProxyError` exception instead.  This fix has been released as part of requests 2.9.2.

Normally, `requests` unwraps the `MaxRetryError` exception for you, but *not for this specific exception*. If you can’t upgrade to 2.9.2 or newer you can catch it specifically (unwrapping two layers now):

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import ProxyError as urllib3_ProxyError

try:
    # ...
except ConnectionError as ce:
    if (isinstance(ce.args[0], MaxRetryError) and
        isinstance(ce.args[0].reason, urllib3_ProxyError)):
       # oops, requests should have handled this, but didn't.
       # see https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3050
       pass
```

or apply the change from the pull request to your local install of `requests`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Great answer, hope other people can find help here as well.

Comment: I think there is actually a requests.ConnectionError on the outside that needs to be caught (if you look at the hierarchy of the exceptions)